# SpringBoot and Jigsaw autoconfiguration

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I am planning to write an app based on SpringBoot and Jigsaw. I am having a couple of concerns about autoconfgire as soon as properties will be split between three Jigsaw modules. I am planning to have three modules: Main module(with application.properties) file, API module (cxf-based REST api which requires properties such as endpoint and some tls-related staff) and DBService module(using mybatis and autoconfigure properties.) As far a I understand for now all of them will contain in their module-info.java the following modules

```
require spring.boot;
requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
```

So the question is: how three properties files must be combined? Or I don't need to do this and put everything to one file? In such case the question is: how to access resources via module-info?